# Randomized Algorithm in $O(d)$ for Solving Unknown Degree $d$ Polynomial Function Using an Erroneous Oracle

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, discrete-mathematics

Consider the field $GF(p)$, where $p$ is a prime number. If there is a function $f: GF_p \times GF_p \rightarrow GF_p$ which has an unknown degree $d$ polynomial, with $1 < d < p / 4$.

Although $f$ is unkonwn to us, there is an erroneous oracle $O$ satisfy the following property:
$\underset{(x,y)\in GF_p \times GF_p}{Pr}[O(x,y) = f(x,y)]\ge1 - \frac{1}{20d}$.

The question asks us to come up with a randomized algorithm which makes $O(d)$ queries to the oracle $O$ and returns the correct value of $f(0,0)$ with probability at least 0.9.

The following is my thinking process: the probability of $O(0, 0) = f(0, 0)$ is at least $1 - \frac{1}{20d}$ according to the condition before. If the probability is at least 0.9, then $d$ should be $d \ge \frac{1}{2}$. Then $p$ should be larger than $2$. We can assume the expression for $f$ is $a_db_dx^dy^d + a_db_{d-1}x^{d}y^{d-1} + a_{d-1}b_dx^{d-1}y^d + a_{d-1}b_{d-1}x^{d-1}y^{d-1} + ... + a_0b_0$. There are total $d^2$ number of items in the function. The randomized algorithm is that we could randomly select the value of $x$ and $y$ from $GF_p$, and at the following $d^2$ steps, we decide the parameters of the polynomials.

```
for i from 1 to d steps:
    for j from 1 to d stpes:
         randomly assign the values of other parameters except a_ib_j;
         solve the value of a_ib_j using the randomly assigned x, y and 
         the result queried from Oracle with x and y;
```

This is just my general idea. The problem is I do not know the degree $d$, so I cannot decide the exact number of steps $d^2$. And even if I know the degree $d$, how can I manage to decrease the time from $O(d^2)$ to $O(d)$?

Or maybe I am going in the wrong way. Can somebody help me with this?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not the general form of a polynomial of degree $d$ in two variables.

Answer (score 3):

Some hints:

Could you solve the problem if the function was of the form $f : GF_p \to GF_p$, i.e., a univariate polynomial?  I suggest solving that special case first.  The below are some hints on how to do that:

If the error was zero, would you know what to do?  Could you devise a strategy that would always work in that situation?  How many queries would your strategy need?

Now suppose you applied your strategy, in the situation where there could be errors (but with the error probability bounded as you've described).  What's the probability that your strategy gives the wrong answer?  What's the probability that your strategy gives the right answer?

You might find it useful to use a [union bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality).

Can you think of any way to check whether a possible solution is correct?

Finally, once you can solve the univariate case, can you think of any way to repeat that procedure multiple times to handle the situation of a polynomial in two variables?

Comment: Thanks for replying! If $f$ was a univariate polynomial and error was zero, then we only need one query to know the exact value of $f(0)$. If the error was $\frac{1}{20}$, just one query is not enough. We could query $O(0)$ for multiple times, say $t$ times, and see the frequency of each value. We could pick the most frequent value and regard it as the value of f(0). Problem is how to choose number of $t$ to make sure the value we have picked is correct with the probability of at least 0.9. Maybe unionbound is useful, but I am not sure how to use it. Could you give more hints? Thanks.

Comment: @davidHoooo, If there's error, $O(0)$ might give the wrong answer every time.  Forget about recovering $f(0)$ for a moment, and think of ways you know of to recover an entire polynomial.  Can you think of any other way to recover the polynomial?  How many points are needed to determine a line?  How many for a quadratic?  How many for a polynomial of degree $d$?  Does it matter where those points are?

Comment: For a polynomial of degree $d$, we need $d + 1$ points to determine the graph. For a univariate function $f$, the randomized algorithm could be: in $i$th step, randomly choose $x$ and other parameters to compute the value of $a_i$ using the result from O(x). After $d + 1$ steps, the polynomial could be determined. If the error was zero, the result would be correct. If error was $\frac{1}{20d}$, the probability the result would give a wrong answer is $\frac{d + 1}{20d}$ by the union bound principle. Then the probability of the opposite is $0.95-\frac{1}{20d}$.

Comment: The problem is $d$ is unknown to us. We do not know exactly how many queries we should do to determine the polynomial. Could you please explain a little more about this? Thanks

Comment: @davidHoooo, it's not hard to check $d=1$, then $d=2$, then $d=4$, etc., until you find one that works to give you a polynomial that agrees with $O$ on all inputs (except with exponentially small probability of error).  (You can even follow up by binary search to find the smallest $d$ that works, but that's probably not necessary.)